# selenium web driver no longer working correctly

Tags: python, firefox, selenium

I am using the selenium module in python and it has been working as expected until I had to update firefox today. After the firefox update, everytime webdriver.Firefox() is assigned to the variable driver, the firefox web browser opens in a default page and then the python program stalls waiting without executing the rest of the code. I am new to selenium so I do not know if there is a work around for this.

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC

driver = webdriver.Firefox()
driver.get(#somewebsite)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you need to upgrade selenium to 2.45, which was released today.

check out: https://pypi.python.org/pypi/selenium

or

pip install -U selenium

Comment: That's awesome! Can you provide a download link please?

Comment: Appreciate that. Thanks!